# How to Access Database created through Wordpress in PHP using laravel framework

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-4, phpmyadmin

I have created one Website using Wordpress and all the data is coming from this website is stored into database.And more importantly that database is created using Wordpress only. So now i want access this data through another website which is developed through php(laravel framework) and i have access to that database through phpmyadmin but i am unable to access that database because that data is stored in encoded form by wordpress.

I have tried integrating wordpress in laravel framework but that didnt worked for me.
For any other solution please help me.

Comment: Just include wp-load.php file in your laravel framework then you can use all the wordpress function in you laravel framework

Comment: But where to include this file? can you tell me specific location

Comment: I don't know the differences between wp and laravel in reading data from their db's. But duplicating some wp functions into your laravel site basically should work. Of course you first have to make quiet a few adjustments to make the function work.

Comment: Ok you need to include the file into the index.php of laravel framework

Comment: after copy pasting the content of wp-load.php into index.php of laravel i am getting few errors. like=main(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\zoilo_admin\public/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='C:\wamp\www\zoilo_admin\vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib;.;C:\php\pear')

Answer (score 2):

Found some tutorial here [Laravel & Wordpress together](http://grossi.io/2014/working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together/), I haven't tried it.